# How to trigger a method on refresh on all pages using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The below function needs to execute on all pages on refresh no matter which route currently is.

example:  `this.executeonEverypage()`

Comment: please add code blocks showing what your implementation is so far so people can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `App.vue` the created / mounted methods allways will be triggered on refresh, you can call this method there.

If it's not enough please give more details.